# Program only works with small numbers

Tags: c

Here's the sample problem:

Lili is a celebrity on a social media platform called GI. She already has 1 million followers in 3 weeks. Bibi also wants to
have a lot of followers, then Bibi asked Lili. After Bibi got advice from Lili, her followers doubled everyday.
Now Bibi wants to know how many followers Bibi will have after K days from now if she has N follower today.

Constraints:
1 <= N <= 128;
1 <= K <= 30;

Here's my code so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n,k,temp;
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);

    for(temp = 1; temp <= k; temp++){
        n = n * 2;
    }

    printf("%d\n",n);

    return(0);
}
```

The thing is this code only works with smaller numbers. When I try to enter N as 2 and K as 30, the results ends up being negative. Tried with some bigger combinations of N and K and I get 0. I do get the desired results with smaller numbers like 7 and 3, so I thought it was a problem with variable size, but using unsigned long didn't help either. N = 2 and K = 30 still ended up as -2147483648.

How do i meet the constraints given?

Comment: use long long instead of int

Comment: tried using long long as well, but the result is still the same

Comment: "Using unsigned long" how exactly? And did you update the `printf` call to match?

Comment: actually 2^k, not N in this case, but 128*2^30 is bigger than even 32bit unsigned int can hold.

Comment: I think @aschepler is right. Use printf("%lld", n)  and long long for n.

Comment: As an aside, this looks like C, not C++. Either you're actually learning C, which is great, or your instructor needs lessons on what C++ is.

Comment: Ah right sorry, i added the wrong tag there. And thx, i found my problem. I forgot to update the printf and scanf to long long as well. Sorry for being careless there.

Comment: Add: `#include <stdint.h>` and use `uint64_t` with `printf("%" PRId64 "\n", t);` I guess..

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow):

> In computer programming, an integer overflow occurs when an arithmetic
>   operation attempts to create a numeric value that is outside of the
>   range that can be represented with a given number of digits – either
>   larger than the maximum or lower than the minimum representable value.

In other words, the data type your using can't store numbers larger than a certain value. Choose another type to store larger numbers (`unsigned long long` instead of `int` for example). There also exist libraries that provide types that can store arbitrarily large numbers, usually at the cost of processing speed.

Another reason that you should use an unsigned integer of some kind is because the answer simply will never be negative. That releases the bit that signifies the sign of the number and doubles the positive range of values that can be stored.

Comment: I see now the problem was in printing the value, but I'll leave this here regardless. Might have been the same underlying issue in the `printf()` call.

Answer (score 0):

your `data-type` selection depends largely on the range if inputs you are operating on.
the selected `data-type` however has a [limit](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm) ( largely depends on the processor and stuff but the this link should do for now ) and exceeding the limit will eventually create overflow.

in your case the range is `1 <= n <= 128` and `1 <= k <= 30` and the `for-loop` for highest possible inputs `n = 28` and `k = 38` evaluates to

```
n = 128*(2 pow 0) + 128*(2 pow 1) + 128*(2 pow 2) + 128*(2 pow 3) + .. + 128*(2 pow 29)
```

the resulting value of `n` from above is way more than the maximum value `int` can hold vitz, `2147483647`as a result you run into [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow).